# Seamlessly integrate external SSD into system storage

Tags: ssd, external-disk

I'm wondering whether there exists a tool that allows me to seamlessly expand my internal SSD drive. It should be a bit like the Dropbox offline feature: I can select files and then they are automatically transferred to my external drive, symlinked, and somehow marked in Finder so it's easily recognizable that this files requires my external SSD to be attached to access it. What's the advantage of this? I don't need to replicate my folder structure when I just want to move a single file instead of the whole directory tree.

Ideally, this tool should automatically recognize based on given properties which files can be moved (e.g., very large and rarely accessed files) and then move them or propose them to me to mark as movable.

**Does such a tool for macOS exist?**

Comment: [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) seems to do that but I haven't tried it out yet.